# ASP.NET Webforms: Recreate a Postback View on Client-side without calling Event Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls, postback

This is just a curious (potentially stupid) question. I am fairly new to ASP.NET but...

I was testing out some functionality on my ASP.NET Web forms page and every time I test I have to *select some options on a few drop-down lists and hit a submit button*, at which point the triggers a post-back.

The *select some options on a few drop-down lists and hit a submit button* action feels mundane and I wanted to know... **what changes client-side when you trigger a post-back?** and... **is there anything I can do in the browser/inspect tool that will return to me the same page view/result of the post-back without *select some options on a few drop-down lists and hit a submit button* without data maintenance through page life-cycle (Session/ViewState).**

I was thinking the only way was to copy the entire HTML on the triggered control event page and have it render that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ASP.NET server injects a system JavaScript block with the **__doPostBack** function. Each postback control on a page calls this function with corresponding parameters. See [Doing or Raising Postback using __doPostBack() function from Javascript in Asp.Net](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack()_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx) for details.

The server generates a full page during a postback and sends it in HTTP response body to the client. As a result, the entire page is refreshed in a browser. If you do not want to send full page postbacks, I suggest you use UpdatePanel:

[UpdatePanel Control Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx)

[Introduction to the UpdatePanel Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)